# Elastic Collisions and Relative Velocities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, inertial-frames

In a 1D elastic collision, it is well-known that the relative velocities of the two objects (before and after the collision) are reversed. What is the extension of this result to 2D or higher? Is there an analogous result for 2D or 3D collisions (the two objects are not travelling along the same line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a 1D elastic collision, it is well-known that the relative velocities of the two objects (before and after the collision) **are reversed**.

When you say *reversed* do you mean that each object keeps their own velocity just with a change of sign?

That would *not* always be the case for a 1D situation. If a resting block $v_{1,before}=0$ is hit by a moving block $v_{2,before}>0$ of equal mass, then the resting block will start to move and the other one will stop, $v_{1,after}>0$ and $v_{2,after}=0$. If the masses are not equal, then even if they move towards each other they may after the collision be moving in *the same* direction at different speeds. See the GIF's in this [this link](http://www.hoomanr.com/Demos/Elastic2/).

> What is the extension of this result to 2D or higher

For a 2D or 3D case you can split the velocity into components. If two objects hit each other with an angle, the perpendicular velocity components will behave as in the 1D case, while the other component will remain unaltered.

[image]

See [this link](http://www.hoomanr.com/Demos/Elastic2/) for a good demonstration.

---

**Addition**

[image]

Each ball might have its own $x$ and $y$ components (see the left drawing on the illustration).

We place the coordinate system so that they each have one component pointing towards each other while the other components are parallel. This will always to be possible to do.

The straight-on component - *the perpendicular component* - causes the collision. If that component was the *only one* present (middle drawing) the balls would hit head-on as in the 1D case. This component will be altered at a collision because of *momentum conservation* as in the 1D case.

If the *other* component - *the parallel component* - was the only one present (right drawing), then there would never be a collision. This component will *not* be altered at any collision caused by any other component.

It is always possible to position the coordinate system in a manner so that *one* component only acts in the  perpendicular direction to the other ball. And so, this component alone will cause collision and this component alone will experience changes due to conservation of momentum.

Therefore, any collision in 1D, 2D or 3D will happen as was it 1D. I hope this helps.

---

**Another addition**

To give an example consider this situation of two balls. Equal mass to keep it simple, but might have different velocities:

[image]

The momentum of each ball is constant in the y-direction (perpendicular to the "axis" of collision shown). Only the momentum-components that are perpendicular to the surfaces (along the "axis" of collision) are changes, as only they interact with each other. For an elastic collision momentum will be conserved and:

$$v_{A1,x}+v_{B1,x}=v_{A2,x}+v_{B2,x}$$

**For the billard table example** you bring up in the comments, the same situation is the case, but one ball is initially at rest:

[image]

The y-components are still constant and the x-components are not. (Masses are assumed equal.) If the ball was hit head-on it would move straight away backwards. But as in this case, by letting the balls collide with an angle they will roll off in directions other than the original one.

Comment: Steeven, thanks for taking the time to provide this Answer. You stated "while the other component will remain unaltered". I don't think that's true in general. I can think of scenarios where both components change.

Comment: @user12707 Can you provide an example?

Comment: Steeven, one example is the oblique collision of two billiards balls - one stationary, one moving, then the two will have a component of momentum in the perpendicular direction, unless it's exactly head on.

Comment: @user12707 You say there is a "perpendicular direction". This is one dimension. No matter how the balls move you can always consider them as having one component in this direction (you can define your coordinate system to fit to this). So in this example as in any other, the collision in itself will always be along *one* axis (1 dimension).

Comment: Steeven, I'm not sure if I'm following what you're saying. If one ball is moving in direction x, collides with another ball, then the first will have both x and y components of velocity. So could you explain how this is still 1 dimension? Thanks.

Comment: @user12707 I added a drawing to the answer. I hope this helps to clear things out. The collision itself will always happen along one single axis and so is 1 dimensional.

Comment: Steeven, thank you for your drawing. This does indeed clarify what you mean. But I disagree. "If that component was the only one present (middle drawing) the balls would hit head-on as in the 1D case." This would imply, if you have two billiards balls left in a game, and form a line that does not intersect with a hole, then you would never be able to score. We should go for a beer and a game if you're ever in town.

Comment: @user12707 No, it would **not** imply that. If you make the balls hit head on, then yes, both will follow the same line, since the component perpendicular to the surface is along that line. But if the second ball is hit at an *angle*, then the perpendicular component also has an angle and is not along the same line as before. That is exactly why you shoot the balls and aim for them to hit slightly to the side on other balls - then the perpendicular force pushes them away at an angle. And I would enjoy going for a beer and a game of pool anytime :)

Comment: So that means, initially, there was only 1 component (along the same direction as the moving ball). After the collision, the component perpendicular to the initial velocity will also be non-zero. Doesn't this contradict what you said? "And so, this component alone will cause collision and this component alone will experience changes due to conservation of momentum." Because both components experience changes.

Comment: @user12707 Time for another drawing :) I added an example with a billard ball. Is this making it clearer what I mean?

Comment: Steeven, yes, you have convinced me :) Beer and billiards are on me if we do meet someday!

Comment: @user12707 Cheers :-)